# How to save a "Image" with "text" overlapped on it in firebase storage in flutter?

Tags: image, android-studio, text, flutter, dart

I have an flutter app,where i am adding a text on a image for creating a meme and then when clicked on the save button only the image is stored in firebase not the text which i have added on the image.i want the whole image with text to be stored in firebase storage..[Like this](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mememaker-33992.appspot.com/o/image_cropper_1569324354937.jpg?alt=media&token=0bdcf41b-c21b-46c9-888e-cb18603d988a)

Following is the code i have already tried..

```
  import 'dart:io';
  import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
  import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

 import 'package:path/path.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:meme_maker/image_picker_handler.dart';
 import 'package:meme_maker/image_picker_dialog.dart';
  import 'categories.dart';
  import 'uploadpost.dart';
  import 'main.dart';

  class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   HomeScreen({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;
    @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
    }

   class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin,ImagePickerListener{

  File _image;
  AnimationController _controller;
  ImagePickerHandler imagePicker;
   int _counter = 0;
   void _incrementCounter() {
setState(
        () {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
      }

   @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    );

  imagePicker=new ImagePickerHandler(this,_controller);
   imagePicker.init();


    }

  @override
  void dispose() {
_controller.dispose();
super.dispose();
  }



 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async{
  String fileName = basename(_image.path);
  StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image,);
  StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot=await uploadTask.onComplete;
  setState(() {
    print("Profile Picture uploaded");
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Profile Picture Uploaded')));
  }
  );
}

return new Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset : false,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title,
    style: new TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white
    ),
    ),
  ),
  body: new GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => imagePicker.showDialog(context),
    child: new Center(

      child: _image == null
          ? new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Center(
                  child: new CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 80.0,
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF778899),
                  ),
                ),
                new Center(
                  child: new Image.asset("assets/images/photo_camera.png"),
                ),

              ],
            )
          :new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

          new Container(
            height: 400.0,
            width: 400.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xff7c94b6
              ),

              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new ExactAssetImage(_image.path),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),


              border:
              Border.all(
                  color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 5.0
              ),
              borderRadius:
              new BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(10.0)
              ),
            ),
          ),
          HomePages(),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,

            children: <Widget>[

         new Container(
          child:new Align(
          alignment:Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: RaisedButton(
            elevation: 5,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("Done"),
            onPressed:(

                )
            {
              uploadPic(context);
              Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
            );
              //UploadStateScreen();
            },
          ),
    ),
  ),

            ],
          ),
          //HomePages(),
        ],
      )
       ),
      ),

    );
  }

   @override
   userImage(File _image) {
     setState(() {
  this._image = _image;
    //HomePages();
    }
     );
    }

    }

 class HomePages extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _HomePagesState createState() => _HomePagesState();
  }

       class _HomePagesState extends State<HomePages> {
    Offset offset = Offset.zero;
    File _image;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
  child: Positioned(
    left: offset.dx,
    top: offset.dy,


    child: GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        setState(() {
          offset = Offset(
              offset.dx + details.delta.dx, offset.dy + details.delta.dy
          );
        }
        );
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.white),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                //Add th Hint text here.
                hintText: "Enter Text",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white
                ),

                // border: OutlineInputBorder( borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 
                15.0)),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

    ),
  ),
  );
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to be editable even after saving it to firebase, you cannot relay only on the storage tool because it only saves files and text is not a file. You will have to use the firebase firestore or firebase real-time database. So, you need to store the text in the database along with other data like the position of the text inside the image, and the image URL coming from the storage.

But if the text should not be editable after saving, you should search for a way to make the text part of the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @ahmedAl-yousif..yes i dont want the text to be editable after saving...i need to make the text as part of image..i am not getting the logic for the same..i googled for the same but dint found though..any help is appreciated..thanks

Comment: I don't know any specific why of doing it, but I think it involves `CustomPainter`. see this article https://medium.com/@suragch/how-to-paint-in-flutter-d18c6c26df10

Comment: i tried this "custom painter" @ahmedAl-yousif..and replaced "custompaint" widget with "textfield"..so that i can get expected results..but dint get tough...any other idea or logic is appreciated..thanks..!

Comment: But I think the Idea is to use `CustomPainter` to render both the image and the text.  So, you should not replace it with a text field. You will take the user input via a textfiled, but after that in the background use `CustomPainter` to combine the image with the text. I am not sure how exactly the implementation will be.